# Spring, 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header not present in production

Tags: spring, cors

I have been looking for the cause of this problem for several days.

With localhost the cors config looks correct. I have my headers like this:

[local req](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL8Wr.png)

In production :

[Prod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Jxe.png)

I obtains this error message :

The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

My spring configuration :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new RequestFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(CorsUtils:: isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**", "/auth/userinfos", "/auth/logout","/auth/checkAuth")
                .authenticated().and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(config -> {
            config.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtCustomizer());
        });


        http.csrf().disable();
    }


    @Bean
    JwtConverter jwtCustomizer() {
        return new JwtConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://webapp-front-e2-ne-np-omm-dev-002.azurewebsites.net","http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(
                Arrays.asList(Stream.of(HttpMethod.values()).map(m -> m.toString()).toArray(String[]::new)));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(Duration.ofMinutes(60));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

My front is angular code and back is write with spring. Front and back is not on the same server.

Tried multiple cors configuration but always missing the credential header.